# jQuery Mobile hybrid app on iOS - unable to enter text onto <input> on the first try

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I am building an iOS app using JQM,everything was working fine with the below code

```
                <div class="middleView">
                    <div id="searchBarWrapper">
                        <input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" data-mini="true" id="searchBox" placeholder="enter item code" spellcheck="false" title="Search" type="text" value="">
                        <div id="itemSearchIcon"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <img id="orImage" src="images/dashboard_or.png">
                    <div id="barcodeText">BAR CODE</div>
                    <a data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="none" href="#" id="barCodeButton"><img id="barcodebutton" src="images/dashboard_barcode.png"></a>
                </div>
```

I wanted to change the return key text to search so I made this,

```
   <form data-ajax="false" id="itemLookUpForm">
                    <div class="middleView">
                        <div id="searchBarWrapper">
                            <input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" data-mini="true" id="searchBox" placeholder="enter item code" spellcheck="false" title="Search" type="text" value="">
                            <div id="itemSearchIcon"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <img id="orImage" src="images/dashboard_or.png">
                        <div id="barcodeText">BAR CODE</div>
                        <a data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="none" href="#" id="barCodeButton"><img id="barcodebutton" src="images/dashboard_barcode.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

This is my js content

```
$("#itemLookUpForm").submit( function (event) {
  goToItemDetails();
    event.preventDefault();
} );

$("#searchBox").keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
     {
        goToItemDetails();
     }
});
```

Now I am unable to enter text on the first try but when I tap on the text input again the cursor is visible and I am able to enter text - all this happens only on iOS 7.0, everything seems to be ok in iOS 6.0. I saw [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/756) and [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/iphone-text-fields-fail-to-receive-typed-characters-on-first-try) but that lead me nowhere. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#searchBox").change(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
     {
        goToItemDetails();
     }
});
```

Comment: Tried, does'nt seem to help!